# Textbox две строки по 40 символов

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Нужно имитировать дисплей прибора с помощью textbox. Как сделать, что бы textbox имел 2 строки по 40 символов, вне зависимости от ширины символов?

Comment: Установить свойство `Multiline = true`, использовать моноширинный шрифт и подобрать ширину и высоту тесктбокса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После включения multiline свойства у текст боксов, перенос каждые 40 символов можно реализовать таким кодом

```
        for (int i = 1; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
            if (i%40==0)
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert(i, Environment.NewLine);
```

Или просто:

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(0,80);
if (textBox1.Text.Length > 40)
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert(40, Environment.NewLine);
```

если можно отбросить все лишнее.